# grails spring security rest plugin

Tags: spring, rest, grails, spring-security, grails-2.3

I'm trying restful spring security rest plugin from https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-spring-security-rest-sample.git

I upgrade grails to 2.3.7 and spring security rest to 1.3.4. And all running smoothly.

I'm using postman for testing the rest login.

url: `http://localhost:8080/grails-spring-security-rest-sample/api/login`
form-data: username = user, password = pass

But there's always return error code 400 Bad Request.
Is there something wrong with the config or test?

Thanks,
Didin

Comment: You are attempting to post form data when you should be posting xml or json data to the end point.  If you use Chrome, you could use a plugin like Postman to test the REST endpoints.

Comment: Sorry I do not have any example using jquery.

Answer (score 3):

This is a POST request with content-type as application/json. Refer dev tool again during the call to /api/login, it should be clear.

This is driven by a setting provided by the plugin as below:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
```

If you wish to pass it as url param then switch the above off (in the app). By default setting is to use request url parameter as:

```
//default is true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useRequestParamsCredentials = true
```

In that case the request could look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/grails-spring-security-rest-sample/api/login?username=user&password=pass
```

Parameter name for username and password can also be customized by these settings:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernameParameter=customusername
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordParameter=custompassword
```

Comment: I want to use both json based and params based url handling. 
In config.groovy I enable both. But i am not able to use.

Comment: You cannot use both I think. I have not used the latest version of the plugin for a long long time now. But the idea is to have a POST or a GET call for `/api/login` with corresponding settings respectively. It is a good question for the owner of the plugin you can ask in [github](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest)